# how to get replies and retweets in twitter in iphone

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

how to get the replies and retweets from twitter using sa oauth engine.i mean which twitterengine delegate method is used to get these.i use this for tweets

```
- (void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
```

and this for messages.

```
- (void)directMessagesReceived:(NSArray *)message forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier
```

but cant figure out which method returns replies and retweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution to that,there is an update for the mgtwitterengine at

[twitterengine with retweets](https://github.com/freeatnet/MGTwitterEngine/commit/294035e5e7cde40c7d0239502ee208d872a6c1f6)

which includes retweets and replies also.retweets,replies and timeline is received in the statusesReceived function itself